# ComboBox column in WPF DataGrid with DataTable as ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, datagrid, binding, selectedvalue, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I've got a datagrid bound to a datatable, with a ComboBoxColumn.  The XAML for this column is as follows:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Rep Name" SortMemberPath="RepName" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource EmployeeList}, Path=Employees}"
                      SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=EmpId}"
                      SelectedValuePath="EmpId" DisplayMemberPath="RepName" />
```

My Employees class:

```
public class EmployeeList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

        public EmployeeList()
        {
           ...
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
        {
            get { return _employees; }
            set { _employees = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Employees"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _id;
        public int EmpId
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; OnPropertyChanged("EmpId"); }
        }

        public string RepName { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

The DataTable serving as items source for the grid contains an "EmpId" column and a "RepName" column.  The combobox is populated with all my employees, and when I make a selection, it is reflected in the datatable.  However, when the screen loads, the currently assigned employee is not selected by default in the combobox.  I thought that the SelectedValueBinding property of the combobox would handle this... what am I doing wrong?

**Update for clarification:**

The datagrid is bound to a datatable which includes an EmployeeID column.  Let's assume that when the screen loads, there are three rows in the table with EmployeeIDs 1, 2, and 3.  I need the combobox column in the first row to have EmployeeID 1 selected, the second row to have EmployeeID 2 selected, and the third row to have EmployeeID 3 selected.

Comment: Just curious, are there any databinding errors in the output window when you run?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the `ComboBox` doesn't select the first item in the collection by default?

If that's the case, you should set the property `IsSychronizedWithCurrentItem` on the `ComboBox` to true.  Info about `Selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx).

...

Well, unfortunately upon further research, `DataGridComboBoxColumn` does not have a `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property. :/  But, you can create a `DataGridTemplateColunm` that looks something like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rep Name">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" 
                   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColunm>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: No, the datagrid is displaying employees... the correct employee for each row should be selected in the combobox column when the grid loads.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure that I follow. Does this question seem to address your issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid ?

Comment: Updated initial post to try and clarify... that question doesn't seem to address my problem, because the list of all employees does show up in the dropdown.