# DataGridComboBoxColumn Binding with 2 lists

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have trouble with binding the values of a ComboBox in my DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListeGrilleTarifaire}" Name="dg_ForfaitCommune" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Visibility="{Binding accesGrilleForfaitCommune}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="{x:Static trad:Langues.lblPays}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListePrixUnitaires}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding tarifDestination_PAYS,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="80" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

- My DataGrid ItemsSource is an object of type 'ListeGrilleTarifaire'
- ListeGrilleTarifaire is a list (property) of the object ViewModelGrilleTarifaire. ViewModelGrilleTarifaire is the the DataContext of my user control (where is located my DataGrid).

What I would like to have is:

1. my combobox to list values contained in the list ListePays (`List<string>`) defined in the ViewModelGrilleTarifaire class.
2. The value of ListeGrilleTarifaire.tarifDestination_PAYS has to be automatically binded in the combobox when the DataGrid load ListeGrilleTarifaire objects (in short... it has to bind)

Any help would be welcome!!

Thank you!

a.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this code exactly same that you want but it may help you .

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="150" Header="EstimateIOName">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cbo" ItemsSource="{StaticResource IOList}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=EstimateIOName,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="EstimateIOName"  SelectionChanged="cbo_SelectionChanged" DropDownClosed="cbo_DropDownClosed" ></ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any code issues in your code, just some things that may be happen:

First: ListeGrilleTarifaire.tarifDestination_PAYS must be a property, if its implements INotifiyPropertyChanged better.

Second: ListeGrilleTarifaire.tarifDestination_PAYS must be the same type of ListePrixUnitaires items.

PLease if this do not work for you please explain better the errors...
Hope be helpul to you...

Comment: I will try thid tomorrow. I will also try to use MultiBinding (I never used it but its name looks good) because in fact, that what I want to have. I need a binding to ListeGrilleTarifaire and a binding to ListePrixUnitaires

Comment: Do you want show both, ListeGrilleTarifaire and ListePrixUnitaires? Are both different collection, so you want use multi-bingind? Lets see, how DataGrid should works is DataGrid.ItemsSource should be binding to a collection of an ItemType, then each column  must be refereed to a property of that ItemType. I thought each ListeGrilleTarifaire had a property tarifDestination_PAYS, and you want select the possibles values from ListePrixUnitaires using combo box.

Comment: I finally used this solution and it works : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid), I defined styles for the DataGridComboBoxColumn and it works