# ComboBox does not display existing bound data

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a *ComboBox* defined in a *DataGrid* as shown.  The `ItemsSource` of the *ComboBox* is a List of the custom class `CodePickList` containing `Name` and `ID` properties. The `DisplayMemberPath` is the `Name` property and the `SelectedValuePath` is the `ID` property. The `SelectedValue` is bound to the `GLCode` property on the *DataGrid* `ItemsSource`.  (Note that the `ItemsSource` of the *DataGrid* is a view.)  The *ComboBox* populates properly and the binding of the *ComboBox* selection to the `GLCode` property works as well.  All fine and good for **new** data.  The problem is with the existing data in the `ItemsSource` of the *DataGrid.* The textblock of the ComboBox is simply blank. Apparently the *ComboBox* is unable to match the `GLCode` property on the *DataGrid* `ItemsSource` with the `ID` property on the *ComboBox* `ItemsSource` when the ComboBox ItemsSource loads. These properties are of the same type. WinForms handles this scenario but I can't get it to work in WPF.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EntityDetailsView.View}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{BindingPath=DataContext.CodePickList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding GLCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  IsEditable="False" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                 </DataTemplate> 
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: No need to make a celltemplate like this, you can use a DataGridComboBoxColum, see this post for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: @Hannish, Thank you, I have seen the post you refer to.  You are correct about the CellTemplate but the display problem persists. Other posts lead me to believe that this a timing issue, meaning that the SelectValue is somehow evaluated against the ComboBox too soon or too late. No luck in figuring it out so far.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the GLCode in the ItemsSource for the DataGrid is coming from the Database (through Entity Framework) as a fixed-length string (padded-right).  The ID in the ItemsSource of the ComboBox was a normal C# string.  Therefore, the values did not match and the existing data would not display. The solution was to pad the ID strings in the ComboBox ItemsSource.  The ComboBox now works as expected.