# How to bind to certain property in a list of Model object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have this model:

```
public class Device {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherType SomeOtherStuff { get; set; }
}
```

And this list:

```
ObservableCollection<Device> DevicesCollection { get; set; }
```

which I change from time to time.

I also use a custom `UserControl` I made, this way:

```
<my:MyCustomListControl ItemsSource="{what goes here???}" />
```

this control usage is supposed to shows a list of all `Device`s, but only their `Name` property.

So how do I bind the `ItemsSource` only to the `Name` property of the collection?

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 1):

In case `MyCustomListControl` is inheriting from `ItemsControl`, you can set `DisplayMemberPath` to `Name`.

```
<my:MyCustomListControl ItemsSource="{Binding DevicesCollection}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```