# Binding DataGridComboBoxColumn to a ViewModel property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have a Recipe model that contains IList RecipeLineItems property. A single RecipeLineItem model has an Ingredient model property.

I created an AddRecipeViewModel for entering and saving a new Recipe instance. AddRecipeViewModel has a Recipe property that exposes a new Recipe instance. AddRecipeViewModel also has an ObservableCollection IngredientList that's used to select an Ingredient when adding a RecipeLineItem to Recipe **(binding to this is my problem, as I will go on to describe)**. I have an AddRecipeView which presents my AddRecipeViewModel in a user control.

Here's my problem XAML from AddRecipeView:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Recipe.RecipeLineItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">      
    <DataGrid.Columns>  
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Ingredient" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Ingredient}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Ingredient.Title}" 
        <!-- 
        This doesn't work! I can't bind to the IngredientList property of my ViewModel! 
        -->
            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vm:AddRecipeViewModel}}, Path=IngredientList}"/>
        <!-- 
        This works! 
        -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<!-- 
This also works! 
-->
<ListBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding IngredientList}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Ingredient.Title}"/>
```

I can't figure out how to set the ItemsSource for my DataGridComboBoxColumn for the user to choose an Ingredient when adding a RecipeLineItem to Recipe. I've tried RelativeSource Self, etc to no avail. I'd be grateful for anyone's educated guess on how to make this work!

I have a temporary solution: rather getting an Ingredient list from AddRecipeViewModel, I created a static class for retrieving Ingredients and I added it to my User Control as a StaticResource. I then set my DataGridComboBoxColumn's ItemSource="{Binding myObjectProviderIngredientList" and it works. I'd much rather have my ViewModel provide this list, however.

Comment: So if your DataGrid DataContext is AddRecipeViewModel and this VM has a list of ingredients(IngredientList), have you tried something like: ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.IngredientList RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: Den and Lee O - thanks for your replies. Sorry to reply back late: vacation. Den, I tried your solution - unfortunately I couldn't get it to work, but I understand the principle. Oddly though, I can confirm DataGrid's root element IS using my ViewModel as its DataContext. I'll seek 3rd party software (Snoop or Mole) to see what my DataGridComboBoxColumn is targeting for its ItemsSource and follow up here.