# Binding a WPFDataGrid to ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, itemssource

I am binding a WPF DataGrid to an observable collection.

In Xaml I have

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGSnapshot"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Snapshot}"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="20,45,20,-46"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</DataGrid>
```

This adds eight lines to the grid, the exact number of letters in the word Snapshot. However there is no data from the Obsevable Collection. When I debug the program it shows that DGSnapshot.ItemsSource="Snapshot"

But if I type this in the code

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DGSnapshot.ItemsSource = Snapshot;
}
```

Then the binding works. When I debug then DGGrid.ItemsSource shows a list of data.

So my question is why is the binding not working in the Xaml code, but it is in the C# code?

Has it got something to do with needing

```
<Windows.Resources Something here/>
```

In the Xaml code?

I have read the following posts, but still can't figure it out

[Bind an ObservableCollection to a wpf datagrid : Grid stays empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087131/bind-an-observablecollection-to-a-wpf-datagrid-grid-stays-empty)

[Binding DatagridColumn to StaticResource pointing to ObservableCollection in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211751/binding-datagridcolumn-to-staticresource-pointing-to-observablecollection-in-wpf)

[How to bind WPF DataGrid to ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539022/how-to-bind-wpf-datagrid-to-observablecollection)

My full C# code...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<SnapshotRecord> Snapshot = new ObservableCollection<SnapshotRecord>()
    {
        new SnapshotRecord(){Cell1="Testing", Cell2 = "WPF", Cell3="Data", Cell4="Binding"},
        new SnapshotRecord(){Cell1="Stack", Cell2="Overflow", Cell3="is", Cell4="Awesome"}
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DGSnapshot.ItemsSource = Snapshot;
    }
}

public class SnapshotRecord
{
    public string Cell1 { get; set; }
    public string Cell2 { get; set; }
    public string Cell3 { get; set; }
    public string Cell4 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind to a public **field**. You can only bind to a **property**.

```
public ObservableCollection<SnapshotRecord> Snapshot { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SnapshotRecord>()
{
    new SnapshotRecord() {Cell1 = "Testing", Cell2 = "WPF", Cell3 = "Data", Cell4 = "Binding"},
    new SnapshotRecord() {Cell1 = "Stack", Cell2 = "Overflow", Cell3 = "is", Cell4 = "Awesome"}
};
```

Also if you want to initialize your collection at start time you should reevaluate your datacontext. The easiest is:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Another issue is your XAML. You don't need to specify the source. Change it to

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Snapshot}"
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however it still does not work with this change.

Comment: @GrantMcConville Sorry, I forgot to address another issue. See my edit.

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you set the DataContext to the MainWindow in Xaml? I tried it but came up with a stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @GrantMcConville If you want to bind the `DataContext` to yourself in XAML put this attribute in the `Window` element: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`

However, usually in WPF Applications you have a ViewModel class that you bind to and not the code behind.