# In WPF set selected column value from Datagrid to Combobox (display section)

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, combobox, datagrid, ef-code-first

I have `DataGrid` with `Equipments` in it. And also I have `EquipmnetMakers` class.
Now I made "Edit" button, which can edit all values.
I use `ItemsSource` to fill `Combobox` with all available `EquipmentMakers`.
Now I want to display selected row's `EquipmentMaker` in `Combobox`.

Please Help!

Comment: Please remove the 'entity-framework' and the 'ef-code-first' tags. Your question is not related to those.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several possibilities.

One of them is using the `SelectedItemBinding` property of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.
It must point to the `EquipmentMaker` property (I suppose your `Equipment` class has an `EquipmentMaker` property).

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding EquipmentMakers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    >           
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- Other columns here -->
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Equipment makers"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding EquipmentMaker}">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
                            Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllEquipmentMakers, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
                            Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllEquipmentMakers, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This example expects a view model with an `Equipments` collection and a list `AllEquipmentMakers` which holds all instances of `EquipmentMaker` the user may choose in the combo box.

You may also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid) question. Here a `SelectedValueBinding` is used.