# WPF MVVM DataGrid filtering using ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a WPF MVVM application with a DataGrid and a ComboBox that are binded to the same List of entities in a ViewModel class.
I want to filter the DataGrid entries through the ComboBox selection, what is the proper way to do this? Since I'm working with MVVM, I want to achieve this with data bindings, and avoid useless code behind.

My XAML code is like the following

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="BlogUrl" Binding="{Binding Blog.Url}" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Blog.Url" />
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private SqliteDbContext context;
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        context = new SqliteDbContext();
        Posts = context.Posts.Include(p => p.Blog).ToList();
    }
}
```

In addition, with this code my ComboBox shows duplicates of Urls, how can I distinct these values?

Thanks.

Comment: ref another [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

**ViewModel**:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private SqliteDbContext context;

    public ObservableCollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    private string _selectedUrl;
    public ICollectionView PostsView { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        context = new SqliteDbContext();
        Posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>(context.Posts.Include(p => p.Blog));
        PostsView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = Posts }.View;
        PostsView.Filter = post => SelectedUrl == null || SelectedUrl == ((Post)post).Blog.Url;
    }

    public string SelectedUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedUrl = value;
            PostsView.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PostsView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BlogUrl" Binding="{Binding Blog.Url}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Blog.Url" 
          SelectedValuePath="Blog.Url"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedUrl}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the `ComboBox` to a collection of the unique urls that you create in the view model.

You could then filter the `DataGrid` by binding the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to a source property of the view model that filters the `Posts` source Collection.

Please refer to the following code sample.

**View Model:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly SqliteDbContext context;
    private readonly List<Post> _allPosts;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        context = new SqliteDbContext();
        _allPosts = context.Posts.Include(p => p.Blog).ToList();
        _posts = _allPosts;
        Urls = _allPosts.Where(p => p.Blog != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Blog.Url)).Select(p => p.Blog.Url).ToList();
    }

    private List<Post> _posts;
    public List<Post> Posts
    {
        get { return _posts; }
        set { _posts = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public List<string> Urls { get; set; }

    private string  _url;
    public string  Url
    {
        get { return _url; }
        set
        {
            _url = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();
            Posts = _allPosts.Where(p => p.Blog != null && p.Blog.Url == _url).ToList();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="BlogUrl" Binding="{Binding Blog.Url}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Urls}" SelectedItem="{Binding Url}" />
```