# Binding Related Data in DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a datagrid that works fine for displaying data, but now I want to use it to edit data.  How do I configure a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to display the description, but bind to the ID of the related table?

My data comes into the application via EF, but to get correctly filtered data into the `DataGrid`, I use a `DbQuery` to create a `List<>` which is then set as the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource`:

```
private void OnControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  DbQuery<Product> whiteGoodsProductQuery = this.GetWhitegoodsProductsQuery(myEntities);
  List<Product> lstWhiteGoodsProducts = whiteGoodsProductQuery.ToList<Product>();
  dgridWhitegoodProducts.ItemsSource = lstWhiteGoodsProducts;
}
```

This populates the `DataGrid` as so:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgridWhitegoodProducts" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <!-- Manufacturer -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manufacturer" Binding="{Binding Manufacturer.CompanyName}"  />
    <!-- Product -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ProductName }" />
    <!-- Description -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Description" Binding="{Binding ProductDescription }"/>
    <!-- Length -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length (mm)" Binding="{Binding Length}"/>
    <!-- Width -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Width (mm)" Binding="{Binding Width}"/>
    <!-- Height -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Height (mm)" Binding="{Binding Height}"/>
    <!-- Price -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, I want to change the Manufacturer `DataGridTextColumn` into a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` so that users can select a different manufacturer.  When I set up the ComboBox column, I don't get any data, so I'm obviously doing something wrong in the binding.

Here's what my combo box column initially looked like:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Manufacturer"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ManufacturerID, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Manufacturer.ID" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Manufacturer.CompanyName" />
```

Currently it looks like:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Manufacturer" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding 
    ManufacturerID}" SelectedValuePath="ID" DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ManufacturerList}" />
```

With the ItemsSource coming from a static ObservableCollection in the code-behind.

```
public static ObservableCollection<Manufacturer> ManufacturerList = new 
    ObservableCollection<Manufacturer>(new MyEntities().Manufacturers);
```

I have tried a number of variations of [TableName.]Field in the SelectedValuePath, SelectedValueBinding etc properties, to no avail.

The next thing I tried was to create a list List in code-behind that the ComboBoxColumn could bind to, but when I set the List as the ItemsSource, I get: `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=ManufacturerList; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=14427695); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')`.

Changing that List to an ObservableCollection didn't work either, nor did making it static.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and which way I should go from here?

Comment: Where do you set `ItemsSource` of the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid) topic can help you.

Comment: That's in the xaml.  I didn't include it because I had tried a few different things in there.  I have tried setting ItemsSource to {Binding Manufacturer}, and to the List / ObservableCollection I created in code-behind.  I generally get this error:  `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element`

Comment: Show how you set `ItemsSource` and also show property in view-model that set as items source.

Comment: @Maxim Updated. um, it's not proper mvvm, so view-model == code-behind.

Comment: `{StaticResource Manufacturer}` What it is? Where `Manufacturer` defined? Anyway if `ManufacturerList` defined right in the code-behind of window this should work: `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ManufacturerList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Mode=OneWay}"`

Comment: Sorry for typo, yes, it's {StaticResource MaufacturerList}.

Comment: In this case you do absolutely wrong thing since `MaufacturerList` is not a resource. Use `ItemsSource` binding I've provided above, it should work. And please take some time to learn WPF basics.

Comment: I changed the ItemsSource as you suggested.  This came back with `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.ManufacturerList; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=36678780); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')`
My 'window' is a UserControl, so I changed AncestorType to: x:Type UserControl, but got the same error.

Comment: Show where you set `DataContext` of the `UserControl`. Also try to use approach from the answer to this question: [Binding ItemsSource of a ComboBoxColumn in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: I have a `<UserControl.Resources><ResourceDictionary><ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries><ResourceDictionary Source="DataCollectionSource.xaml" /></ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries></ResourceDictionary></UserControl.Resources>` where DataCollectionSource.xaml holds `<CollectionViewSource x:Key="InventoryViewSource" Source="model:Products" ... />`.  The model namespace points to the EF generated model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind to public *properties* and `ManufacturerList` is a field.

If you define this as a non-static property in the code-behind of your `UserControl`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Manufacturer> ManufacturerList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Manufacturer>(new MyEntities().Manufacturers);
```

...you could bind to it like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Manufacturer" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ManufacturerID, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        SelectedValuePath="ID" 
                        DisplayMemberPath="CompanyName">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ManufacturerList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ManufacturerList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

`ID` and `CompanyName` are supposed to be public properties of the `Manufacturer` class and `ManufacturerID` is a public property of the `Product` class.

The reason why you need to set the `ItemsSource` property in the styles is that a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is not a visual element that gets added to the element tree and therefore it has no visual ancestors.

**Edit:**

> So apparently the `DataContext` of your `UserControl` is a `CollectionViewSource`. This is an example of why you should *always* provide a [reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of your issue when asking a question.

Anyway, you could define another `CollectionViewSource` in your `UserControl` and set the Source of this one to your collection of `Manufacturer` objects and bind the column like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ... ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ManufacturerList}}" />
```

...where `ManufacturerList` is the `x:Key` of the `CollectionViewSource`.

Comment: I had set up the list as a property in some of my previous attempts, then I tried to make it static then I figured a property can't be static and changed it to a field.  Anyhoo.  I followed your suggestion and received: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ManufacturerList' property not found on 'object' ''CollectionViewSource' (HashCode=1121399)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.ManufacturerList; DataItem='ProductsTabData' (Name='ucProductsTabItem'); target element is 'TextBlockComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: If it helps, my app is a `Window` holding a `TabControl`, holding multiple `UserControl`s (that I'm calling 'TabItem').  The TabItem resources include a `ResourceDictionary` containing multiple `CollectionViewSource`s.  This is where the main data for the app comes from.  I'm wondering if I should add another CollectionViewSource to capture the Manufacturers?

Comment: Thank you mm8.  I didn't realise the existing data context would cause a problem as everywhere was saying that the DataGridComboBoxColumn was not in the tree and so I figured that part was unimportant.  I do apologise.  Thank you.  Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a user control resource like bellow

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="UserTypeList" Source="{Binding DomainUserTypes}" /> </UserControl.Resources>
```

2. Bind the Data grid Combo column as below

   DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="User Type"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserTypeList}}
3. DomainType will be the view model property.

   DomainUserTypes = new ObservableCollection();

just populate the View model property with data and test, it will work.