# combobox in datagrid using mvvm and caliburn.micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have tried for days now to add a combo box in a data grid using MVVM and Caliburn.Micro.
*I have tried almost every suggestion out I could find - no luck!*

My Xaml is in a user control - Name and Test are showing fine!

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Players" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308">    
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test" Binding="{Binding Position}"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ComboBoxColumn" Header="Position"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Position}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MissingCTypeViewModel : Screen, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Positions { get; set; }

    public MissingCTypeViewModel()
    {

        Positions = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Forward", "Defense", "Goalie" };
        Players = new ObservableCollection<Player>(){
                new Player() {Name = "Tom",Position= "Forward"},
                new Player() {Name = "Dick", Position= "Defense"},
                new Player() {Name = "Harry", Position= "Goalie"}
            };
        //ComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = Positions;
        //dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Players;
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Position { set; get; }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGuUF.png]

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have tried this before also - but no luck!
Still nothing in Position Column and Combobox is empty

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5409259/1136211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `DataGridComboBoxColumn` `ItemsSource` binding to `Positions` collection.

Note, that you need to have it as a **static** resource - see: [Binding ItemsSource of a ComboBoxColumn in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid)

XAML:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TheNamespeceOfYourApp.ViewModels"

<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test" Binding="{Binding Position}"/>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="ComboBoxColumn" Header="Position"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Position}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:MissingCTypeViewModel.Positions}}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

ViewModel:

```
public static List<string> Positions = new List<string>() { "Forward", "Defense", "Goalie" };`
```

Comment: SelectedItem is not available in <DataGridComboBoxColumn>?

Comment: Indeed, my bad, I mixed it with standard ComboBox. How did you bind ItemsSource? If you don't see any dropdown value, this is where I'd look for error.

Comment: I edited my post with working solution. please check.

Comment: Making Positions static is a workaround. However, it could still be a property: `public static List<string> Positions { get; } = ...`

Comment: That Worked :)
`public static List<string> Positions;`
`Positions = new List<string>();`
`Positions.Add("Forward");`
And so on...

Comment: remember that this is a static field, and if you will use Add method calls in non-static constructor, each time you will create view-model instance, you will add to the list another set of values. As @Clemens suggested using static field is a workaround and you either should have it initialized only one time (in static constructor), use enum or have it defined in static resource/separate static class.