# Observablecollection from interface add to listview via binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have an application that draws use of Xabre.ble plugin.

When the application scans for devices, once a device is discovered the application appends it to an ObservableCollection which derives from an interface.

I have made a Data template in Xaml that i wish to populate, but for some reason i can't seem to get the BindingContext right.

Basically, what I want to achieve, is to add device objects to my `ObservableCollection` `IDevice`, and fetch just the name of the individual devices in the bindingcontext for the user to see in the listview

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="deviceList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/> 
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <local:IconView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="BLE.png" Foreground="#3b5998" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
                   <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding DeviceName}" TextColor="Teal"/>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Cs:

```
public ObservableCollection<IDevice> Devices { get; set; }
IAdapter adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
public ObservableCollection<string> DeviceName { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
    //Instantiate observable collection
    Devices = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
    DeviceName = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    //Appending peripherals to list
    BindingContext = DeviceName;
    deviceList.ItemsSource = BindingContext;
    Content = deviceList;
    Refreshcmd();
}
public void Refreshcmd()
{
//DeviceDiscovered is an event, when it discovers a device, we fire the eventhandler
    adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
    {
        if (a.Device.Name != null)
        {
            Devices.Add(a.Device);               
            DeviceName.Add(a.Device.Name);
        }
    };
    adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
}
```

As you can see, I have tried to make an object which contains a string with just the name of the IDevice. However, it doesn't append to my databinding `DeviceName`.

Furthermore, I don't really like this solution, as I would much rather be able to access the `Devices.Name` from the interface, but that is not allowed apparently. 
- the reason why I would much rather like that solution is that the user eventually will have to connect to a device from the list, meaning that it is much easier to have one object for all the "behind the scenes" details.

Comment: Its a different control but your problem is similar to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: Had another look at what you are doing - try to change `<Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding DeviceName}" TextColor="Teal"/>` to this `<Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding}" TextColor="Teal"/>`

Comment: Why are you messing with the `BindingContext` ? Why can't the `MainPage` be the `BindingContext` for your XAML ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you try to use two lists? `Devices` and `DeviceName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor your code, to a MVVM approach.

```
namespace YourNameSpace.ViewModels
{
    public class YourViewModel
    {

        private ObservableCollection<IDevice> devices;
        public ObservableCollection<IDevice> Devices
        {
            get { return devices; }
            set
            {
                devices = value;
            }
        }
        public YourViewModel()
        {
            Devices = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
        }
    }
}
```

In your Page.xaml.cs

```
public partial class YourPage : ContentPage
    {
        public YourPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new YourViewModel();
        }
    }

    public void Refreshcmd()
{
//DeviceDiscovered is an event, when it discovers a device, we fire the eventhandler
    adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
    {
        if (a.Device.Name != null)
        {
            (YourViewModel)Devices.Add(a.Device);               
            //DeviceName.Add(a.Device.Name);
        }
    };
    adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();
}
```

Then in Page.xaml

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}"
              CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
```

Comment: It works, but if i for example want to show the IDevice.Id, would I then just go {Binding Id} ? cause it doesn't show anything in that case.

Comment: Yes, in your ViewCell, you just need to Bind to the IDevice Property you desire.

Comment: In that case, I just wrote {Binding Id} but it doesn't show anything. I guess it doesn't affect anything that it is Int. It still should show right?

Comment: Yes, it should show even though its int. Have you tried to Bind to other properties? Are they showing correctly?

Comment: Hmm, i just tried printing the Rssi state, and that actually seems to work just fine!

Comment: So the ID should work as well. Check if the object is all correctly set