# WPF Binding list to datagrid editable combobox column

Tags: c#, wpf

So currently I can bind a list of objects to a combobox column from the code but I am having a hard time making it editable

See my code below

My Xaml

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="dgEmpcmbName" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Employee name" Width="Auto"/>
```

My cs file

```
dgEmpcmbName.ItemsSource = people.ToList();
dgEmpcmbName.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
dgEmpcmbName.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

If anyone know how to make it editable or just add an event on SelectionChanged that would be awesome

Thanks

Edit:

Btw this is not a duplicate as I have seen the solutions with the datagrid template column but when I use a template column I can't bind the list from the code.. (I am not saying it is not possible I am saying I can't.. If you can please assist :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your column differently by created a template column and creating the ComboBox in the data template, with the bindings.

This was based off of this answer found here: [Editabe DatagridComboBoxColumn in WPF using C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b4937fe-459a-4ee0-ab2c-bc57f1cc6b64/editable-datagridcomboboxcolumn-in-wpf-using-c?forum=wpf)

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Employee name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding People.Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedValue="{Binding People.ID}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Edit:
I think this is what you are looking for.  In this example, I have a viewmodel which I bind to the XAML form.

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel 
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        GridItems = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>() {
        new GridItem() { Name = "Chef", PeopleId = 1 } };

        PeopleItems = new ObservableCollection<PeopleItem>() {
        new PeopleItem() { ID = 1, Name = "George" },
        new PeopleItem() { ID = 2, Name = "Martha" } };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GridItem> GridItems { get; set; }
    public static ObservableCollection<PeopleItem> PeopleItems { get; set; }
}
public class GridItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PeopleId { get; set; }
}

public class PeopleItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then your XAML form:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    >
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MainWindowViewModel.PeopleItems }}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Name"
SelectedValuePath="ID"
SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CompanyID}" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Using your DataGridTemplateColumn, this is how I would do it.  I found an example which I borrowed heavily from, [See Answer from Slauma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: but how do I bind my ItemsSource through xaml cause I have my list in my cs file? btw Thanks for assisting

Comment: @Hancs What is your viewmodel bound to your xaml? can you post that?

Comment: Code behind -> Datahandler -> Class -> Interface
(ps Sorry if I misunderstood, I am still a second year student and only learning the basics now.)

Comment: Basically all I want to know is how do you bind your people list to the combobox template on the UserControl loaded event