# How do i populate a Combobox in a Datagrid with a List in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How do i add a list with items to a Combobox inside of a Datagrid?

Outside of the Datagrid (for a normal combobox) i could do

```
List<string> myStringList = new List<string>();
    myStringList.Add("Item 1");
    myStringList.Add("Item 2");

ComboTest.ItemsSource = myStringList;
```

Which would populate the ComboTest Combobox, with the 2 options 'Item 1' and 'Item 2'

From the XML side i haven't been able to populate it either with the `ItemsSource="{Binding ...}` option

The XML code looks as follows

```
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="comboTest" Width="*">
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Status" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

and neither of the two before mentioned options will work with a Combobox in a `<DataTemplate>`.

If i put a Combobox in a `<DataTemplate>` it will show the Combobox but will be empty and i won't be able to give it a value from the C# code. If i go with the code shown above it won't even show the Combobox at all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding ItemsSource of a ComboBoxColumn in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use a `CollectionViewSource` that you add to the XAML markup of your window or user control:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="Window26" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" />
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
```

Set its `Source` property to your list programmatically:

```
(Resources["items"] as CollectionViewSource).Source = myStringList;
```

...and bind the column to the `CollectionViewSource` in the XAML markup:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}" />
```